# Android: How to change a drawable in a item list from other Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, drawable

I'm starting with Android, I could create a `ListView` and it works perfect. This list contains an image representing a task status (active or inactive), when clicking on a list item opens a new activity where you can modify the task, changing its data or state.
I want to ensure, that when the user returns to the task list, the item for the task which was working will be update (change the image that represents its state).

How can I do that in the activity which works on the selected task?

This is my code that open new activity for selected iten in `ListView`:

```
listTareas.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String tarea_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tarea_id)).getText().toString();

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleItemActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_TAREA_ID, tarea_id);
        startActivity(in);
    }
});
```

I can send the id of drawable that I want to change, but how can I handle it on `SingleItemActivity`? Is that possible?

Thank you guys.

Greetings. -

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the drawable associated with an ID.

You should call `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` and then when you return from `SingleItemActivity` the method `onActivityResult` will be called. Use this to update your dataset that the `ListView` populates from.

Once you've updated the data you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ListView`'s adapter.

Comment: OK, thank you. Just have a doubt, onActivityResult works when user press the key "Back" in his cellphone?

Comment: You will need to override the onBackPressed method in the second activity to finish with a result

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() and you need to override method

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
```